# Angular 2 - Make raw JS change a model of a component

Tags: angular

I'm actually working with Leaflet and I need to bind a pop up where when the user clicks, this must navigate to a page via Angular 2 router.

But I need to send raw HTML with raw JS to the popup and I cannot use any directive into the popup.

```
let html = '<div onClick="Change the variable of some ngModel variable so I can handle it using ngChanges;">Popup content</div>'; 
marker.bindPopup(html);
```

Any idea how to produce it ?

Comment: use `(click)` instead of `onClick`,

Comment: nope...you did't understand. I need to create a variable with raw html to send to a 3rd party script - Cannot send angular stuffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was really unable to solve this in an elegant way. so I did in this fashion:

```
<input #gourl type="text" style="position: absolute; left:0; width:0; height:0" id="dummyInput">

html += '<div style="height: 20px; color: #7E1877; cursor: pointer" onclick="document.getElementById(!dummyInput!).value=!' + s.data[i].rooms[j].id +',! + Math.random();">' + this.myVar + "</div>";

html = html.replace(/!/g,"'");

lastUrl = "";
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    setInterval(function() {
        if(t.input.nativeElement.value != t.lastUrl){
            console.log(t.input.nativeElement.value);
            t.lastUrl = t.input.nativeElement.value;
        }
    },300);
}
```

So, the recipe:

- create an inputbox and hide it
- in your raw (non angular 2) JS, set the value of the inputbox
- create a timer to detect changes and retrieve the values.

Why not use ngOnChanges ? Looks like ngOnChanges can't track elementRef/nativeElement.